# Relationships in back-end forum OctoberCMS

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relationship, octobercms

i'm trying to create back-end Relationships (be more specific one to one type) with partly success, if I'm inserting information throw php-my-admin information show up, but when i try to enter information throw OctoberCMS back-end form, then information is recorded just in first major table, but not in second.

So I have two tables (first one, major)randman_random_rooms with fields [id, view, places, cleaned] and  randman_random_room_description with fields [id, description, room2_id] in my room2s.php model i have

```
public $hasOne = [
   'roomdescription' => [
       '\Randman\Random\Models\RoomDescription',
       'key' => 'rooms2_id',
       'otherKey' => 'id'
   ],
];
```

and in model rooms2 columns.yaml

```
roomdescription:
   label: 'description'
   relation: roomdescription
   select: decription
   type: text
```

and finally in my rooms2 fields.yaml

```
 roomdescription:
    label: description
    span: auto
    oc.commentPosition: ''
    type: number
```

so what am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look for roomdescription type: "number". It is relation not a number. You probably should change roomdescription type to: "relation" and use [Relation Widget](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-relation). Or if you want put exact id number use proper id field name. For further debug you can use [trace_log()](http://octobercms.com/docs/services/helpers#method-trace-log) function that will put sql queries to your log file.